# How can a wordpress plugin generate pages without posts?

Tags: plugins

I would like to hidde all posts in a wordpress home page, so I need to remove `loop_start` or `the_post`.  I tried the `remove_action` function, but this does not remove posts. Any ideas how a plugin can generate empty pages?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a plugin, but WordPress already has settings to allow a static front page to exist for the blog. Go in the WordPress Admin screen and look under Settings>Reading and you'll see that you can set the blog front page to be a single Post/Page that you choose. This will do what you need without making a plugin.

If you're dead set on making a plugin, here is a useful tutorial on doing this in code: http://mindleaks.com/wordpress-adding-teaser-in-static-front-page-of-thesis-theme/

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to show your post on homepage, you can create a static page for homepage, and crate another page for hosting the post. You can tell wordpress which page to use as homepage, which page to use for post, the settings are in wp-admin/settings/read/